# Determine if AuthorizeAttribute is at Class level or Method level

Tags: asp.net-mvc, vb.net

I'm creating a custom AuthorizeAttribute, and I'd like to check inside the New() method of custom AuthorizeAttribute if the current attribute been declared at the class (controller) level or the method (action) level.

My controller:

```
<CustomAuthorization>
Public Class SeomController
...
    <CustomAuthorization>
    Function Index() As ActionResult
```

My CustomAuthorizationAttribute:

```
Public Sub New()
    ' Determine if we're at Controller level or Action level
```

Comment: you can add a parameter and use that.. `CustomAuthorization(Level=Levels.Class)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Attributes [do not (or at least they should not) have any behavior](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/13/passive-attributes/), so making a self-aware attribute is not recommended.

But if you take the approach in the linked article, you can create a global `IAuthorizationFilter` that determines where your attribute is registered.

## CustomAuthorizationAttribute

First of all, you need a "dumb" authorize attribute that is just an attribute (not an `AuthorizeAttribute` subclass) to mark your controllers and actions with. It is just smart enough to collect the metadata and split it into arrays for easy access, but that is it.

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.[Class] Or AttributeTargets.Method, Inherited := True)> _
Public Class CustomAuthorizationAttribute
    Inherits Attribute
    Private m_users As String
    Private m_usersSplit As String()
    Private m_roles As String
    Private m_rolesSplit As String()

    Public Property Users() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_users
        End Get
        Set
            Me.m_users = value
            Me.m_usersSplit = SplitString(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Public Property Roles() As String
        Get
            Return Me.m_roles
        End Get
        Set
            Me.m_roles = value
            Me.m_rolesSplit = SplitString(value)
        End Set
    End Property

    Friend ReadOnly Property UsersSplit() As String()
        Get
            Return Me.m_usersSplit
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend ReadOnly Property RolesSplit() As String()
        Get
            Return Me.m_rolesSplit
        End Get
    End Property

    Friend Shared Function SplitString(original As String) As String()
        If String.IsNullOrEmpty(original) Then
            Return New String(-1) {}
        End If
        Return (From piece In original.Split(New Char() {","C})Let trimmed = piece.Trim() Where Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(trimmed)trimmed).ToArray(Of String)()
    End Function
End Class
```

## CustomAuthorizationFilter

To determine where your attributes are located, you can inherit `AuthorizeAttribute` (which implements `IAuthorizationFilter`) and then add some logic to it to determine where your attribute is registered.

Generally, you should override the `AuthorizeCore` method and return either true or false to indicate whether the user is authorized, so that is where I am showing the decision logic.

```
Public Class CustomAuthorizationFilter
    Inherits AuthorizeAttribute
    Private Enum Level
        Action
        Controller
    End Enum

    Private Function GetCustomAuthorizationAttribute(actionDescriptor As ActionDescriptor, ByRef registeredLevel As Level) As CustomAuthorizationAttribute
        Dim result As CustomAuthorizationAttribute = Nothing

        ' Check if the attribute exists on the action method
        result = DirectCast(actionDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType := GetType(CustomAuthorizationAttribute), inherit := True).SingleOrDefault(), CustomAuthorizationAttribute)

        If result IsNot Nothing Then
            registeredLevel = Level.Action
            Return result
        End If

        ' Check if the attribute exists on the controller
        result = DirectCast(actionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.GetCustomAttributes(attributeType := GetType(CustomAuthorizationAttribute), inherit := True).SingleOrDefault(), CustomAuthorizationAttribute)

        registeredLevel = Level.Controller
        Return result
    End Function

    Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(httpContext As HttpContextBase) As Boolean
        Dim actionDescriptor = TryCast(httpContext.Items("ActionDescriptor"), ActionDescriptor)
        If actionDescriptor IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim registeredLevel As Level
            Dim authorizeAttribute = Me.GetCustomAuthorizationAttribute(actionDescriptor, registeredLevel)

            ' If the authorization attribute exists
            If authorizeAttribute IsNot Nothing Then
                If registeredLevel = Level.Action Then
                        ' Attribute is registered on an action
                        ' Implement user and role checking logic using
                        '
                        ' authorizeAttribute.RolesSplit
                        ' authorizeAttribute.UsersSplit
                ElseIf registeredLevel = Level.Controller Then
                        ' Attribute is registered on a controller
                        ' Implement user and role checking logic using
                        '
                        ' authorizeAttribute.RolesSplit
                        ' authorizeAttribute.UsersSplit
                End If
            End If
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Public Overrides Sub OnAuthorization(filterContext As AuthorizationContext)
        ' Pass the current action descriptor to the AuthorizeCore
        ' method on the same thread by using HttpContext.Items
        filterContext.HttpContext.Items("ActionDescriptor") = filterContext.ActionDescriptor
        MyBase.OnAuthorization(filterContext)
    End Sub
End Class
```

## Usage

Register your `CustomAuthorizationFilter` globally so it can detect where your attributes are (and run any other authorization logic).

```
Public Class FilterConfig
    Public Shared Sub RegisterGlobalFilters(ByVal filters As GlobalFilterCollection)
        filters.Add(New CustomAuthorizationFilter())
        filters.Add(New HandleErrorAttribute())
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then decorate your controllers and actions normally.

```
<CustomAuthorization>
Public Class SeomController
...
    <CustomAuthorization>
    Function Index() As ActionResult
```

Comment: Wow! Yes! Thank you, and thank you for taking the time to write all of this in VB!

Comment: Your welcome. Although, I didn't write it in VB I wrote it in C# and then used a converter :). I think it came out as converted correctly, but let me know if any part of it doesn't compile.

Comment: Yeah, I think `CustomAuthorization` inside CustomAuthorizationFilter showd be CustomAuthorizationAttribute, and the trimmed part doesn't compile, although I see what you're trying to do there...

Answer (score 1):

this is not an answer to your question, but maybe an alternative.

add a property to your custom attribute class

```
Public Enum Levels
    Controller
    Action
End Enum

Public Class CustomAttributes
    Public Class CustomAuthorize
        Inherits System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
        Private _level As Levels
        Public Property Level() As Levels
            Get
                Return _level
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As Levels)
                _level = value
            End Set
        End Property
        Protected Overrides Function AuthorizeCore(httpContext As HttpContextBase) As Boolean
            If (_level = Levels.Controller) Then
                'Controller Level
            End If
            Return MyBase.AuthorizeCore(httpContext)
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```

then you can just indicate where the attribute is assigned when you add it.

```
<CustomAttributes.CustomAuthorize(Level:=Levels.Controller)>
Public Class AccountController

    <CustomAttributes.CustomAuthorize(Level:=Levels.Action)>
    Public Function Login(returnUrl As String) As ActionResult
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl
        Return View()
    End Function
```

Comment: Yup, this is what I was planning to do if I didn't find the solution that doesn't require to put anything extra on the Controller/Action level